# What does this sound mean on my hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-home-server

First of all, I have server with OS Windows Home Server 2008. One of my 2 hard drives (1tb and 500gb) failed, and I don't know if there was any data on it or if I had lost any data. I was only occupying around ~300gb and the 500gb died. Correct me if I am wrong, but Windows Home Server was designed to be okay after a hard drive failure like this right?

For the hard drive failure part, what is this sound?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2VlIhyT34g

Comment: Sounds like somebody's playing PONG.

Comment: Any machine will only be "ok from a hard drive failure" if you set it up so. If there was no data redundancy or hardware redundancy, youre up the stream without a paddle.

Comment: There are evidently gnomes living inside that disk.

Comment: Lowest cost data recovery I have found to date...http://lowcostrecovery.com/pricing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** I'm no hardware expert, this answer is based on personal experience.

You're most likely screwed, this sounds pretty similar to the [Click Of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death) which means that your harddrive is or is close to being dead.

So if there was any data on that drive, you might wanna contact a Data-Recovery Company.

Answer (score 1):

That's the read/write head hitting its outer limits and reseating repeatedly. It's the "click of death". Sound familiar, from my own channel?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0BXBWAChKs

Comment: Hi Dan! Funny how we both have the same broken hard drive with same video / thermaltake.

Answer (score 1):

On Home Server any shares you had duplicated will be fine. If its the system drive the recovery is more complex but again your duplicated shares will be fine. Any data you had on non-duplicated shares is at risk.

FAQ: Drive failure risks

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/whsfaq/thread/828b438f-5770-4f4b-bf82-b5d2f12e3887